# Get count of data from particular Excel cell using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am reading an excel file as below using pandas and writing the results to a dataframe .

[image]

I want to get the count of rows present in "Expected Result" column for each Testcase . I used the len function, it was throwing "TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()" error . Is there a way to capture the row count from excel for each test in python .

Here is my code

```
        df = pd.read_excel("input_test_2.xlsx")
        testcases = df['Test'].values
        expected_result = df['Expected Result'].values
        
        for i in range(0,len(df)):
                testcase_nm = testcases[i]
                _expected = expected_result[i]
                print("Count of Expected Result:" , len(_expected))

This is the Output I am looking for :
Testcase-1 , Count of Expected Result: 1
Testcase-2 , Count of Expected Result: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the dataframe data, it's tough to say if this will work as it's not clear how pandas handles merged excel data.

in general though:

```
df_counts =  df.groupby('Test').count().reset_index() # won't give you the text, but a new dataframe
```